# password_verify does not work

Tags: php, password-hash

Hi I've got a problème with my verif password (PHP-7).

this is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['change_pass'])){

    global $conn;
    $id = '1';

    $pass = password_hash($_POST['pass'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $conf_pass = $_POST['conf_pass'];
    $verif_pass = $_POST['verif_pass'];

    $query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM bdd WHERE id='$id'");
    $data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(!empty($pass) && !empty($conf_pass) && !empty($verif_pass)){

        if(password_verify($conf_pass, $pass)){

            if($pass == $conf_pass){

                $update = $conn->query("UPDATE bdd SET password='$pass' WHERE id='$id'");

                if($update){
                    echo 'Mot de passe changé';
                }else{
                    echo 'Erreur SQL';
                }

            }else{
                echo 'Les mots de passe ne correspondent pas'; var_dump(password_verify($conf_pass, $pass));
            }

        }else{
            echo 'La confirmation du mot de passe actuelle est erronée';
        }

    }else{
        echo 'Vous devez compléter tous les champs';
    } 
}
```

and the error message is that: 
**Les mots de passe ne correspondent pasbool(true)**

someone see wat's wrong ?

Comment: `password_verify` should be for the unhashed password and the DB password.

Comment: `$pass == $conf_pass`, this will always be false, `$pass` will contain a hash, but `$conf_pass` will be the plain password.

Comment: That fail ^^ i'm tired, thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Please re-read `password_verify` [documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

`password_verify` is not for confirmation of password. It hashes the first argument(with salt) and compares it to the second argument:

`bool password_verify ( string $password , string $hash )`

`$password`: Raw password

`$hash`: Hashed password(usually queried from DB)

return value: whether password is correct or not.

**NOTICE**
The `hash` argument, must be calculated with `password_hash`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use parameterize queries for all DB interactions involving user input.

The `password_verify` takes parameter 1 as an plain text password and parameter 2 as the hashed value (usually the DB value). So you need to change your usage of that function. Hash it just for the storage.

```
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$conf_pass = $_POST['conf_pass'];
$verif_pass = $_POST['verif_pass'];
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT password FROM bdd WHERE id=?");
$query->execute(array($id));
$data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if(!empty($pass) && !empty($conf_pass) && !empty($verif_pass)){
    if(password_verify($pass, $data['password'])){
         $update = $conn->query("UPDATE bdd SET password= ? WHERE id= ?");
         $update->execute(array(password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT), $id));
```

Also if only selecting one column, use its name, not `*` it will save you resources.

Answer (score 0):

All is done,

I've got do a bad replace, this is the correct code:

```
if(!empty($pass) && !empty($conf_pass) && !empty($verif_pass)){

    if($verif_pass == $data['password']){

        if($conf_pass == $_POST['pass']){

            $update = $conn->query("UPDATE hyona_ftelecom_web_users SET password='$pass', first_connect='1' WHERE phone='$phone'");

            if($update){
                notify('success','Succès','Votre mot de passe a bien été changer.');
            }else{
                notify('danger','Erreur','Erreur SQL.');
            }

        }else{
            notify('warning','Attention','Les mots de passe ne correspondent pas.');
        }

    }else{
        notify('warning','Attention','La confirmation du mot de passe actuelle est erronée.');
    }

}else{
    notify('warning','Attention','Vous devez compléter tous les champs.');
}
```

Comment: How does `$verif_pass == $data['password']` work? The DB is hashed, no? Also how does that verify work? Plain text won't == a hashed value.